Unable to open subfolder on external drive - input/output error EXT4 partition
Sorry - this has been asked and answered 100 times but here's a new wrinkle...
Helping a buddy transition his world to Linux from Win10.
He has an 8TB external drive.  I have made a few NTFS partitions to be able to read/write from Win and Linux and one EXT4 partition.
He has been sorting through his family photo collection and all was going well.
I stopped by yesterday and we moved a huge folder from his internal nvme to the EXT4 partition on his external drive.  No errors.
Time went by...  Then we went to open that partition in Nautilus again and suddenly got this error:

Sorry could not display all the contents of "Parent folder": Error when
getting information for file "/media/user/Ext4Partition/Parent
folder/#1 important photos here/2021 Vacations": Input/output error

I moved to the command line -
Here are the complete mount parameters of the partition in question:

mount
dev/sdb1 on /media/user/Ext4Partition type ext4 (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names,iocharset=utf8,uhelper=udisks2)

I can CD into the Parent folder (where nautilus gave us the error).  But then listing the contents gives me an error
ls: cannot access '2021 Vacations': Input/output error
I started running chkfs but sorta chickened out - I should really back this folder up before going any further
QUESTION 1 What is the easy way to copy all OTHER subfolders out this partition... all folders have similar names - four digit year and subject...  Is there a way to do a cp command for all folders except '2021 Vacations'?  Or any way to do it inside Nautilus?  Or I could install Nemo or any other fun utility.
The chkfs ran for a bit before I crashed it
sudo fsck /dev/sdb1
Ext4Partition: recovering journal
Ext4Partition contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Error reading block 103284768 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Entry '2021 Vacations' in /#1 important photos here (177733633) has deleted/unused inode 25821185.  Clear<y>? no
Entry '2021 Vacations' in /#1 important photos here (177733633) has an incorrect filetype (was 2, should be 0).
Fix<y>? no
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Unattached inode 25821201
Connect to /lost+found<y>? no
Unattached inode 25821202
Connect to /lost+found<y>? no
Unattached inode 25821203
Connect to /lost+found<y>? no
Unattached inode 25821204

Question 2 This is an EXT4 journaled partition on a new drive (18 months maybe) should I even worry?  Are the errors above a sign of high concern or should I just let chkfs do it's thing.  Or use Disks and click repair file system - isn't that going to be the same.  The only advantage - my buddy is new so I can get him to run disks and click... He's not ready to do much at the cli.
Question 3 Is there any chance that this is caused by huge long path names?  I cleaned up the names in this post but in reality the folder names are descriptive and don't follow all unix rules - so '#1 look here for all pictures to be sorted***' is an example sub folder.  Probably not at all important but I noticed that the mount line to the partition includes the windows_names switch and it made me pause.
Thanks in advance for your help!
Regards - Frank

When I first decided to convert to Ubuntu in 2006, I changed Windows to use CamelCase, under_score or justonename or no spaces like Windows uses. If you have spaces you have to "escape" them in all commands usually with "" or quotes around full name so space also  inside quote. Be sure to have good backups before this: Change all files to have underscore
rename 's/\ /_/g' %F  See man rename for more info. May need sudo also. I have used Ubuntu for years and still try to run some commands & it says error, but then just needs sudo. Most need sudo if not just in /home.

Hey Fred - You must be the hardest working man in Linux.  You have helped me through a bunch of dual boot grub questions over the years - so thanks again for that.
But yep - I understand it is best to use better file and folder names.  But today that is too late for that lesson.
Is their any chance you have thoughts on the 3 questions I highlighted?  I am tempted to just let chkfs do it's repairs.  I am wondering if the warning is just very conservative.  An EXT4 file system should be pretty resilient?

Abnormal shutdown can corrupt a file system. Or any power failure or user interruption of activity. I have occasionally had to run fsck. Back in Windows days I think I ran chksk even more often. Not sure what fix on Entry '2021 Vacations' would do?

Yep - typo above from my Win days...  I meant how likely am I to lose data if I let fsck finish and answer Y to everything.

Usually you do not lose data or maybe one corrupt file that cannot be recovered. But sometimes the worst happens & that is why we want really good backups. Also is drive good. You can check drive with Smart Status. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools If you have Disks, it also is in the hamburger icon in upper left corned. Lots of detail but all I really know is passed or fail. Bad or lose connections can also cause issues. External drive could have lose USB connection or bad cable. And some older USB adapters do not like some drives, large or gpt. And you need separate power.
